# Which is the bigger order of growth ? (Big-O)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

n<sup>n</sup> or 2<sup>n<sup>2</sup></sup>. I think that the *n* term will grow faster than the *2* term and the n<sup>2</sup> will grow faster than the *n* term, but overall will the n<sup>2</sup> exponent cause the second to grow faster.

Comment: log is your friend

Comment: This is really not a SO question. math.stackexchange.com would be a better place.

Comment: @someWittyUsername how did you do that math formatting ?

Comment: @ChrisIkeokwu You can look at the source.

Comment: @eleanora what  do you mean?

Comment: @ChrisIkeokwu click edit on the question and look at how the math formatting was done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's get *ln* from both sides:

```
log (n ^ n) = n log n
log (2 ^ (n ^ 2)) = n ^ 2
```

Obviously *n ^ 2* growths faster than *n log n*. It means that *n ^ n* growths faster than *2 ^ (n ^ 2)*.

Comment: Small comment - *ln* denotes natural logarithm, while you compute the binary logarithm here